# r - trying to make a function write to the same dataframe

Tags: r

I am new to R and am struggling with the problem described later. I found posts here looking at problems with the same error message, but couldn't find any solution that applied to my problem. I hope someone here can help.

I have a function that will return a dataframe (always 3 columns (pencil name, price, date), and usually about 90 rows). This is to write a follow on blog post for http://pencil.land/?p=2677 . To feed the function I give it a URL.

I have a vector with a list of 15 or so URLs and I want all of those fed into my function and get a big dataframe with all results back.

I want let R call the function for each URL in the vector and record the result
I thought it could be done in an easy way, like:

```
result <- lapply(absoluteaddress, scrapearchive)
```

but I get

> Error in data.frame(pnames, price, archivedate) : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

`absoluteaddress` is the vector with the URLs. `scrapearchive` the function that will create the dataframe.

...but that doesn't work.

I think I might need `rbind` so that all the data frames that are returned by the function are in the same data frame, but I couldn't find a way of making that work.

Another solution might be is `scrapearchive` would always add to the same dataframe, but again, I couldn't find a way of making that happen.

I would be very happy if someone could help.

```
scrapearchive <- function(address) {
  #exampleuse 
  # test4 <- scrapearchive("https://web.archive.org/web/20140417064443/http://www.cultpens.com/acatalog/Pencils.html")

  library(rvest)

  #get date out, ignore time as unlikely for price to have changed so not worth recording this info
  archivedate <- regmatches(address, gregexpr("20[0-9]{6}",address))

  #pencils <- html("https://web.archive.org/web/20130730001143/http://www.cultpens.com/acatalog/Pencils.html")
  pencils <- html(address)

  # pencil product names
  pnames <-
    pencils %>% 
    html_nodes("p a") %>%
    html_text()

  # web page formatting will result in empty lines
  # remove empty lines
  pnames <- grep ("[a-z]", pnames, value=TRUE)

  # product names into vector pnames
  paragraphs <-
    pencils %>% 
    html_nodes("p") %>%
    html_text()

  #remove all entries without a pound sign
  paragraphs <- grep ("£", paragraphs, value=TRUE)


  # only keep prices
  t1 <- regmatches(paragraphs, gregexpr("£([0-9])+.[0-9][0-9]",paragraphs))

  # only keep first price
  price = do.call("rbind", lapply(t1, "[[", 1))


  # both vecors into a dataframe
  df <- data.frame(pnames,price, archivedate)
  # names for the columns
  names(df) <- c("name", "price", "date")

  #spell it out so that it gets returned
  df
}
```

and

```
library(rvest)
overview <- html("https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.cultpens.com/acatalog/Pencils.html")

# archive.org doesn't use css, so can't use rvest?

urls <-
  overview %>% 
  html_nodes("date captures") %>%
  html_text()



overview <- readLines("http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.cultpens.com/acatalog/Pencils.html")

# Get lines with links
htmllines <- overview[grep("<a href=\"/web/20", overview)]


# \/web.*\.html
# \/ matches the character / literally
# . matches any character (except newline)
# Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times
# can check at https://regex101.com

# get address out 
# R needs escape characters escaped!!!!!
relativeaddress <- regmatches(htmllines, gregexpr("\\/web.*\\.html",htmllines))



absoluteaddress <- paste0 ("https://web.archive.org", relativeaddress)

#http://nicercode.github.io/guides/repeating-things/
result <- lapply(absoluteaddress, scrapearchive)
```

Comment: once you get a list of `data.frames` you can use `do.call(rbind, listOfData)` to join it into one.  But, it sounds like there is a problem with your `scrapearchive` function

Comment: You can try to use a for loop instead to call all the urls and rbind the responses into one data frame.

Comment: Legalizelt, thank you. The problem is that according to my understanding I can't do that with lapply.

Keon, thank you. I thought of doing that, something that comes more natural to me as I am used to PHP, not R, but it seemed as if the easier R way is to use lapply. I will look into how to do loops in R.

Comment: The problem is that `pnames`, `price`, and `archivedata` return different length vectors.  For example, with that first url, the first two are empty, and the second is length 1, hence the error ... rows: 0, 1.  What is the function supposed to do with empty data?

Comment: I thought they have different levels, but the same length. Hm, I'll try to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `do.call` to bind a list of `data.frame`s into one

```
f <- function(l) data.frame(l=l, x=sample(100, 10), y=sample(100, 10))
urls <- sample(letters, 10)
do.call(rbind, lapply(urls, f))
```

Edit: One way to deal with the missing data would be to wrap the `data.frame` construction in a `tryCatch` block.

Replace:

```
# both vecors into a dataframe
  df <- data.frame(pnames,price, archivedate)
  # names for the columns
  names(df) <- c("name", "price", "date")

  #spell it out so that it gets returned
  df
```

With:

```
  # both vecors into a dataframe
  tryCatch({
      data.frame(name=pnames, price=price, date=unlist(archivedate))
  }, error=function(e) data.frame(name=character(0),
                                  price=numeric(0),
                                  date=character(0)))
```

Then,

```
result <- lapply(absoluteaddress, scrapearchive)
head( do.call(rbind, result) )
#                                            name  price     date
# 1    Caran d'Ache Bicolor Pencil 999 Blue + Red  £2.00 20140518
# 2           Caran d'Ache JASS Chalk Pencil 2152  £1.91 20140518
# 3                  Caran d'Ache Pencil Extender  £2.84 20140518
# 4              Caran d'Ache Technalo Pencil 779  £2.60 20140518
# 5           Caran d'Ache Technograph Pencil 777  £2.60 20140518
# 6 Caran d'Ache Technograph Pencil 777 Set of 12 £27.85 20140518
```

Comment: Thank you for this. 
I am not sure why it doesn't work with my function.
 I will post my code at the end of the original question (too long for posting it here).

Comment: Your edited answer is exactly what I need. 
Great!!
Thank you very much.